# Mouse over cursor for tag badge is different from cursor for regular tag in the profile page

Tags: bug, design, badges, profile-page

In the [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) the mouse over cursor for the next regular badge tracker is ... regular (i.e. a pointer or text selector):

> [image: regular]

But for the next tag badge the cursor looks like a hand:

> [image: tag]

The windows that popped-up after clicking look similar, so I think the mouseover behaviour, including cursor type, should be same.

Moreover, for the recently earned (newest) regular badge the cursor works like for a tag badge, i.e. hand styled:

> [image: newest]

Comment: @Laurel ["text selector"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Kbk.png) appears when mouse pointer covers the text in the badge. Thanks for editing!

Comment: I’m sure someone asked a related question just a few days ago…

Comment: Cross-site dupe on Meta.SO: [Click pointers on badges \[profile feature\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374600/4642212).

Comment: @Xufox no it's not a duplicate. One is  reporting a potential bug, one is a feature request.